# How to get symfony messenger Messages before handler consumes them?

Tags: php, symfony, rabbitmq, symfony-messenger

I wonder how to get messages which are waiting in my Failed queue from a controller, before the handler consume them.
I don't persist them with doctrine, I put them in a rabbitmq that I can see them from the rabbit admin interface.

Comment: Have you configured failed_transport!?!? If you have that queue, you can proof call console command messenger:failed:show from a controller function.

Comment: Yes as I can see these messages in my rabbitmq admin UI. When I record failed messages with doctrine the failed:show command works, but when I persist them in rabbitmq I got the message " There are 40 messages pending in the failure transport. The "failed" receiver does not support listing or showing specific messages". So they exist, but I can't get them from rabbitmq.

Comment: In that case you could configure the failed queue with doctrine as transport, you won't have problems getting the messages.